# Distro Recommendation!

Tags: linux-distribution

I've been using `Manjaro` `xfce` for the past few months and it worked flawlessly. But recently the OS has been freezing randomly while using any browser. Since I've already been thinking of hopping to another distro, do you guys have any recommendations for my specs:

- CPU: Intel Pentium P6100 @1.999GHz (~2.0GHz)
- RAM: 4Gb DDR3
- Graphics: On-board graphics
- Storage: 320GB HDD
- Age(laptop): about 10 years old

And I use my PC mostly for :

- Web browsing
- Zoom meetings
- Playing a few(native) arcade games like sudoku, solitaire, tetris, etc.
- And a little programming.

Please recommend any distro that does work finely with my specs and my daily demands.

I've been considering Kde Neon, is that a good choice as per my above specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from my personal experience with older hardware and lightweight OS and software:

I have used both `Fedora` and `Mint` linux distros with `Cinnamon` and `Mate` desktop environments. Both have proved to do pretty well when running web browsers such as Brave and web-based video conferencing.

Also, I personally find KDE to be resource intensive.

Comment: While KDE might not be resource intensive but KDE tends to run slow and laggy on HDD's. But in terms of customization nothing beats KDE.

Comment: You sure you want to trust and recommend a browser funded by Peter Thiel?